# how to get format code of built-in character control in .NET?

Tags: .net

I want to format a number which built-in format code such as: C, N, G.... but how can I display their actual code for user to see it? Because C, N, G is too ambigous, displaying as sequence of #, 0 is more comprehensive.

Please help.

Comment: Please elaborate with some example inputs and expected outputs.. and you'd have a better chance of getting an answer. Sounds easy to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

N, C, G, F, etc, are the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), any other numeric format string interpreted as a [custom numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

The standard format strings won't give you the same formatted result always, they are [Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87k6sx8t.aspx) dependent, and they will be interpreted differently depending on the current thread or specified culture.

For example:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-us");
CultureInfo deDE = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

double number = 120.50;

number.ToString("C", enUS);  // outputs $120.50
number.ToString("C", deDE);  // outputs 120,50 €
```

Comment: I see that it changes according to specific cultureInfo. So if I have the cultureInfo, who to retrieve the format code of "C" for this CultreInfo?